# Множественное наследование в python

Tags: python, ооп, наследование, множественное-наследование

У меня есть вот такая система классов

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        print('c')

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print('a')

class B(C):
    def __init__(self):
        C.__init__(self)
        print('b')

class D(B, A):
    x = 'X'
```

Создаю объект:

```
D()
```

Получаю к моему большому удивлению:

> c
>
> b

Всю жизнь считал, что должно быть так, пока не наткнулся:

> c
>
> b
>
> a

Неужли второй класс-родитель нужно руками инициализировать и вызывать его конструктор? Почему так?

Comment: Вы обращаетесь к классу-родителю напрямую, а это неправильно, потому что нужно обращаться к нему через `super()`, через который питон выстроит правильный порядок вызова

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда создаётся объект класса, интерпретатор пробует найти метод `__init__` в соответствии с **порядком разрешения методов** (MRO) продвигаясь по иерархии наследования до тех пор, пока не найдёт первого предка, у которого этот метод определён, и дальше уже искать не будет.